# How to change the Camera Roll Name in Screen Recorder from Broadcast

Tags: ios, swift, assets, info.plist, replaykit

[image]I have one Screen Recorder with `RPBroadcastActivityViewController` and `Replaykit` when I tap in recorder the application name is `Camera Roll` for start recording I want to change this name to `App Project` name. I don't find Camera Roll Name in Project and I want to Change it

```
class MyScreen: UIViewController , RPBroadcastActivityViewControllerDelegate 

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)
         }


let broadcastPickerView = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: btnRS.frame.width, height: btnRS.frame.height))
    broadcastPickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if let button = broadcastPickerView.subviews.first as? UIButton {
        button.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.white

    }


    btnRS.addSubview(broadcastPickerView)
    broadcastPickerView.tintColor = .yellow
    broadcastPickerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    broadcastPickerView.showsMicrophoneButton = true

    btnRS.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)


}
```